How do we handle the recent announcement of the SHA-3 winner?
The winner of the SHA-3 competition was announced today. We already have a tag edit for sha-3, but some of the questions with sha-3 will undoubtedly reference the contest instead of the new family of hash functions that was chosen.
Do we create a new tag (say sha-3-competition) and retag questions as needed, or do we leave sha-3 to reference both the competition and the newly chosen family?

The name under which SHA-3 will be standardized is not chosen yet (or not announced yet), and a debate over it was raging today on the hash-forum mailing list (the list maintained by NIST for the SHA-3 competition). So I think it is now urgent not to be hasty.
I suggest that we leave sha-3 questions as they are today, and that retagging may be performed only after the naming situation has stabilized.

Good point. I too saw the debate on the mailing list. Quite entertaining.
